# IndexPath in viewControllerToCommit Function

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, 3dtouch

I need to be able to get the `indexPath.row` for my `UICollectionView` in the commit function for Peek and Pop.

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {

    }
```

I need to do this because each row in the `UICollectionView` opens a different view controller and needs to pass information for different rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to present the `viewControllerToCommit` object which should already be filled with the good item of your `UICollectionView`:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location), let cell = collectionView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YOUR_CELL_CLASS else {
        return nil
    }

    previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

    let viewController = YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_CLASS()
    viewController.yourObject = cell.yourObject
    return viewController
}

func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
}
```